# Storing email lists with a variable number of fields

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am looking to allow my users to store their email lists and I am using MySQL.

I want to allow users to decide what fields their email list may have. eg. Name, Email, Location, Birthday

Each user may want different fields and each list may have different fields to each other.

I'm really stuck as to how I should structure my databases to allow for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the total number/type of fields fixed and known, or could it be that a user could even create his own field?

Comment: Great question @TimBiegeleisen, the number of the fields is unknown. The fields will be text or numerical. The user could create his own fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number of fields and the types of fields are possibly unknown, and could change depending on the user, it might not make sense to hard code them as columns.  Instead, I would recommend that you use a key value pair approach here.  First define a table `email_fields` looking something like this:

```
user_id | id | field
1       | 1  | Name
1       | 2  | Email
1       | 3  | Location
1       | 4  | Birthday
```

Above user 1 has configured his email lists to have four fields, which are the ones you gave as an example in your question.  Adding more fields for this user, or adding more users, just means adding more records to this table, without changing the actual columns.

Then, in another table `email_lists` you would store the actual metadata for email address and user:

```
id | user_id | field_id | value
1  | 1       | 1        | Sam Plan
1  | 1       | 2        | sam.plan@somewhere.com
1  | 1       | 3        | Gonesville, AL
1  | 1       | 4        | 1967-03-28
```

In other words, the basic idea is that every email, for every user, would be represented a set of records corresponding to a bunch of key value pairs.

Comment: Relatively simple approach, I like it. To your knowledge is there perhaps some sort of AWS solution that might make my life easier in regards to my question?

Comment: Nothing of which I know per se relative to AWS.  AWS offers its RDS service, which is a fairly low cost database solution.  The free tier might even meet your storage needs already.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking to allow my users to store their email lists and I am using MySQL.

This means that a given user may have more than one email list.

So the appropriate table for storing the email lists should be like this one:

```
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title   | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

> Each user may want different fields and each list may have different fields to each other.
>
> The fields will be text or numerical. The user could create his own fields

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email_list_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| field         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value         | longtext         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here is the SQL query to create those tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `email_list` (
    `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `email_list_data` (
    `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email_list_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `field` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `value` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

In another approach, you will use a different table for storing the fields and another one for storing the values.

```
CREATE TABLE `email_list` (
    `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `email_list_fields` (
    `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email_list_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `field` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `email_list_field_values` (
    `email_list_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `field_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    `field_value` longtext DEFAULT ''
);
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. To your knowledge is there perhaps some sort of AWS solution that might make my life easier in regards to my question?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers remove around metadata. This is great, though it isn't meant for large amounts of data or relationships based on a "record" because there would be no Contact model. You would return 30 records if there were 30 fields specified for the contacts in the list.

It would take 2 parts that are highly complicated to implement, but would be more structured in the end.

## 1) Tenant DB Structure

There are some tutorials out there that can help with this. Essentially, you would have 1 master database that stores your teams, etc. Then, each of your teams would get their own database. We have a project that implements this structure and it works well. You can be connected to both the main and the specific tenant database at the same time.

## 2) Generating migration files

I have never done this part before, but I assume it is possible..

Try making a flexible schema-file builder. You can execute system commands via PHP to save a file you generated into a directory structured on your teams, such as `/migrations/teams/1/37284_user_submitted_migration` or something like that.

## Execute

You can then run the artisan migration command on that specific file, for that specific tenant database (use the Artisan::run() facade helper). Each of your teams could have whatever structure they wish, as if you had built it for them.

This can all be executed within the same job.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and I'll need to do some research on this. To your knowledge is there perhaps some sort of AWS solution that might make my life easier in regards to my question?

Comment: There's DynamoDB, which offers multi-tenancy and I think they're even hinting at different schemas per customer. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/multi-tenant-storage-with-amazon-dynamodb/